# Getting longitude and latitude of user before action

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps

I know how to get longitude and latitude via HTML5 on mobile phone. But problem is how to get user's location everytime before user access google map on my site (locations/map). I need it because I'm using haversine sql to collect data up to 100km around user's location. I was thinking about submitting form with longitude and latitude values, but is is not really efficient since user can directly open url of map (locations/map) and then no values will be posted.

Problem is that I have to use javascript to get lat and lng values, but I'm not sure what is the best way to send ti to sql query

Haversine SQL

```
select("6371 * acos(cos(radians(:MOJLAT)) * cos(radians(geolat)) * cos(radians(geolong) - radians(:MOJLONG)) + sin(radians(:MOJLAT)) * sin(radians(geolat)) )) AS distance_query HAVING distance_query <= 100");

addParams([':MOJLAT'=>$_POST["geolat_beforeaction"], ':MOJLONG'=>$_POST["geolong_beforeaction"]]);
```

HTML5 geolocation

```
if(navigator.geolocation) 
{
    var options= {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 5000,
      maximumAge: 0
    };

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
    (
        function(position) 
        {   
            find(position);
        }, 
        function() 
        {       
          //handleNoGeolocation(true);
        },
        options
    );
} 

function find(position)
{
    //data to post to database. fill input fields with longitude and latitude
    var geoLat, geoLong;
    if(geoLat=$("#geolat"))
    {
        geoLat.val(position.coords.latitude);
    }

    if(geoLong=$("#geolong"))
    {
        geoLong.val(position.coords.longitude);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [`navigator.geolocation.watchPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation.watchPosition) rather than `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`, that way the position will update itself and will be potentially more accurate.

As for the rest of the question, what does your interface look like? Why and when are you submitting a form? Perhaps you could use AJAX to fetch the data?

Comment: It is google maps with pins on it generated from database. I'm submitting the form to send lat and lng coordinates sto haversine sql. AJAX would make things more complicated

Comment: OK, AJAX would make it more complicated, but at least the values you want would be updated more frequently.

Comment: I was thinking about it, but what if user closes browser or disconnects from internet then later refresh site (i'm talking about mobile phone)

Comment: It should still work, why wouldn't it? Let me know what problems you think might occur?